# Probability Distributions: "What Came First: Chicken or the Egg"?

Tags: probability

Suppose we take a Normal Distribution:

$$f(x; \mu, \sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
$$

It is almost accepted as common knowledge that the "true values" of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$  are:

$$\mu = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$$
$$ \sigma = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \bar{x})^2}$$

**I am interested in understanding where these formula for the "true values" come from.**

For example, I know that with Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation), we write the Likelihood Function for any Probability Distribution Function, differentiate this function and set it to 0, and then derive MLE formulas for the estimates of the parameters in this Probability Distribution Function.

An interesting fact associated with MLE is that the estimates are not always "unbiased" (i.e. MLE estimates are not always equal to their "true value"). In the case of the Normal Distribution, MLE produces "biased" estimates for $\sigma^2$ We can show this as follows:

\begin{aligned}
\ell(\mu, \sigma^2 | \mathbf{x}) &= \log\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i; \mu, \sigma^2)\right] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\log f(x_i; \mu, \sigma^2) \\
&
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{d\sigma^2}\ell(\mu, \sigma^2 | \mathbf{x}) = 0
\end{aligned}

$$ \hat{\sigma}^2_{\text{MLE}} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \bar{x})^2
$$
\begin{aligned} Bias = 
\mathbb{E}\left(|\hat{\sigma}^2_{\text{MLE}} - \sigma^2|\right) &=  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \bar{x})^2 - \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \bar{x})^2 \neq 0\end{aligned}

**This brings me to my question:** How exactly do we know what the "true value" of $\sigma^2$ is?

- When we are presented with the formula of the Normal Distribution, do we assume that the "true formulas" for $\sigma^2$ and $\mu$ already exist beforehand and we have to use our own creativity to come up with estimators for them? E.g. Did Carl Friedrich Gauss come up with a cool looking function (i.e. Normal Distribution) that integrates to 1, explicitly defined the "true formulas" for $\sigma^2$ and $\mu$  - and then said "do whatever you want with this function"? (e.g. develop MLE theory to derive estimates of  $\sigma^2$ and $\mu$ )
- Or when we are presented with the formula of the Normal Distribution, we have no choice but to derive the "true formulas" for the estimators of them?

As such, what came first - the "true formulas" for the parameters or did the "true formulas" for the parameters and the "estimators" for the parameters come at the same time?

Thanks!

Comment: You are mixing statistical *sample* formulae with probabilistic formulae

Comment: @ Fshrike: Thank you for your reply! I have a feeling I am indeed mixing something up - perhaps you could help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much!

Comment: You might want to expand the penultimate term, the one still containing the sample mean.

Comment: @ A rural reader: thank you for your reply! Why do you think this might be useful?

Comment: The true value of $\mu$ (and also $\sigma$) is itself! The formulas you wrote are just the unbiased estimators of $\mu$ (and $\sigma$) which converge to the "true value" only $n\to +\infty$. Besides, the estimator for $\mu$ is not unique, they are constructed "after" the so-called "true formula".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\pr}{\operatorname{Pr}}\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$It's unclear what exactly you want. The normal distribution has nothing to do with: $$\mu=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i$$And before we start throwing around equations like the one above we need to first define what about we're talking.

If you have a probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,\pr)$ and a random variable (measurable function) $X:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ then you **define** it's expectation $\Bbb E[X]$, often denoted by "$\mu$" when in context, to be: $$\int_{\Omega}X\d\pr$$

And its standard deviation $\sigma(X)$ or often just "$\sigma$" is to be: $$\sqrt{\Bbb E[(X-\mu)^2]}$$

No $x_i$'s in sight.

---

Now suppose you have $n\in\Bbb N$ and i.i.d random variables $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$ defined on the same probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,\pr)$. Let $X$ denote $X_1$. It is true by simple expectation algebra that: $$\Bbb E[X]=\Bbb E\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^nX_m\right]$$

So in **statistics**, if you have $n$ data points $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\in\Bbb R$ you can compute the **sample** mean $\mu=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^n x_m$ and, if the $(x_i)$ are drawn from some "population variable", you can *hope* that $\mu$ is the expected value of this population variable. It usually won't be, though. However, it is true that you can expect it to be, in the sense of probability, so it is reasonable to use that formula to make a guess. To be clear, in statistics we pretend that the picking of our data points $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ is the same thing as taking an evaluation of some i.i.d random variables $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$, which facilitates the connection with probability.

Now, it is true that: $$\sigma^2=\Bbb E\left[\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{m=1}^n\left(X_m-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^nX_m\right)^2\right]$$

So given the data points $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ you can calculate the *sample* variance; $$s^2:=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{m=1}^n(x_m-\mu)^2$$Where $\mu$ is the computed sample mean, and  probabilistically you can expect it to equal the "true" value $\sigma^2$. But it doesn't actually equal it most of the time.

So, to your question:

> **I am interested in understanding where these formula for the "true values" come from.**

Answer: these are **not** the formulas for the true values! You know the true value of $\sigma^2$ in the sense of probability, if you happen to know the distribution well. I know the variance of a binomial distribution, for instance, and that is because there is a pure mathematical definition of this which can be analytically computed. But if I used the formula $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{m=1}^n(x_m-\mu)^2$ for some sample data $(x_i)$ it'd likely give me the wrong answer.